# Least repeated/items appearing once in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to print unique items, most repeated items, and the least repeated item i.e. occurring once for an array. In the least repeated section, I am not getting any output since the flag is set to 1 instead of expected 0.

Sample Input :

```
10
watch
laptop
iphone
watch
car
headset
laptop
watch
shoe
mobile
```

Sample Output :

```
The unique items are
watch
laptop
iphone
car
headset
shoe
mobile
The maximum purchased item(s) are
watch
The minimum purchased item(s) are
iphone
car
headset
shoe
mobile
```

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ItemDetails {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int flag=0, flag1=0, count = 0, count1 = 0, count2 = 0;
        String maxname = null;
        int k;
//      String[] max = new String[k];
        Integer x = sn.nextInt();

        sn.nextLine(); 
        String[] names=new String[x];
        for (int i = 0; i<x; i++)
        {
            names[i] = sn.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println("The unique items are");
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
                for (int j = i+1 ; j < x; j++) 
                {
                        if (names[i].equals(names[j]))
                        { 
                    // got the unique element 
                            flag = 0;
                            break;
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            flag = 1;
//                          break;
                        }
//                  break;
                }
                if (flag==1)
                {
                    ++count;
                    System.out.println(names[i]);

                }
            }
            System.out.println(count);  
        }
        System.out.println("The maximum purchased item(s) are");
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
                for (int j = i+1 ; j < x; j++) 
                {
                    if (names[i].equals(names[j]))
                    {
                        count1++;
                        maxname = names[i];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        count1 = 0;
                    }
                }

            }
            System.out.println(maxname);    
        }

        System.out.println("The minimum purchased item(s) are");
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
                for (int j = i+1 ; j < x; j++) 
                {
                    if (names[i].equals(names[j]))
                    {
                        flag1 = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (flag1==0)
                {
                    count2++;
                    System.out.println(names[i]);
                }
            }
            //System.out.println(maxname);  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to clear the flag before the inner loop.

Comment: Andreas - Didn't get you. Can you please point to the position?

Comment: You were saying that the "minimum purchased item(s)" section is empty, right? That code has nested `for` loops. Right inside the outer loop (the `i` loop), *before* the inner loop (the `j` loop), you need to clear the flag (`flag1`).

Comment: Tried doing it, but the results are same as in 'The Unique Items' section.

Comment: If your input is `2 foo foo`, then you loop through and see first `foo`, which is followed by another `foo`, so you skip it. The you see second `foo`, and since it is not *followed* by another `foo`, you print it. *Oops!*

Answer (score 0):

@Alan
It might be achieved much simpler using Java streams, for example:

```
    List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
    // Fill List items with your data

    Map<String, Long> processed =items.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                            Function.identity(), Collectors.counting())                        
    );

    System.out.println ("Distinct items");
    processed.keySet().stream().forEach(item -> System.out.println(item));

    Long minCount = Collections.min(processed.values());
    Long maxCount = Collections.max(processed.values());

    System.out.println ("Least repeated items");
    processed.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> entry.getValue().equals(minCount)).forEach(item -> System.out.println(item));        

    System.out.println ("Most repeated items");
    processed.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> entry.getValue().equals(maxCount)).forEach(item -> System.out.println(item));
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually I was trying to do it without using streams. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Retrive unique items:

```
public static Set<String> getUniqueItems(Collection<String> items) {
    return new HashSet<>(items);
}
```

Retrieve purchased items using given `Function` (using `Streams`):

```
private static Set<String> getPurchasedItems(Collection<String> items, Function<Collection<Long>, Long> function) {
    Map<String, Long> map = items.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
    final long count = function.apply(map.values());

    return map.entrySet().stream()
              .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() == count)
              .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
              .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

Retrieve purchased items using given `Function` (using POJO):

```
private static Set<String> getPurchasedItems(Collection<String> items, Function<Collection<Long>, Long> function) {
    Map<String, Long> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (String item : items)
        map.compute(item, (key, count) -> Optional.ofNullable(count).orElse(0L) + 1);

    final long count = function.apply(map.values());

    Set<String> res = new HashSet<>();

    for (Map.Entry<String, Long> entry : map.entrySet())
        if (entry.getValue() == count)
            res.add(entry.getKey());

    return res;
}
```

Retrieve maximum purchased items:

```
public static Set<String> getMaximumPurchasedItems(Collection<String> items) {
    return getPurchasedItems(items, Collections::max);
}
```

Retrieve minimum purchased items:

```
public static Set<String> getMinimumPurchasedItems(Collection<String> items) {
    return getPurchasedItems(items, Collections::min);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually I was trying to do it without using streams.

Answer (score -1):

In a code place for the minimum, set `flag1=0;` before the second loop, also you should sort your array to be able to apply this algorithm. Apart from this two, you need to compare items with before to make sure your algorithm will work properly

```
    System.out.println("The minimum purchased item(s) are");
    {
        Arrays.sort(names);
        for (int i = 0; i < x-1; i++) {
            flag1 = 0;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < x; j++) {
                if (names[i].equals(names[j]) || (i>1 && names[i].equals(names[i-1])) ) {
                    flag1 = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (flag1 == 0) {
                count2++;
                System.out.println(names[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helped.

Comment: @Alan then could you please mark it as approved? At least give +1